# Java paintComponent resize/minimize erases all but last drawn component

Tags: java, jframe, paintcomponent

Problem is specified in the title. I hit run, make a few lines here and there. When I resize or minimize the window, everything except the last line that was drawn is erased from the jframe window. This is part of a much larger photo album program. Eventually, I want to be able to save the drawing and add to the album. I believe the below code is where the issue lies. I've been scratching my head all night on this one. I figured if I created two arraylists and iterated through them, repaint() would re draw everything back, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Please help! Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Draw extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> lines;
private ArrayList<Point> points;
private Graphics g;
private Button clearButton;

public Draw()
{
    clearButton = new Button("Clear slate");
    g = getGraphics();
    points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    lines = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>(); 
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    setBounds(0,0,500,500);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);

    clearButton.addActionListener(this);        

    this.add(clearButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    points.add(e.getPoint());
    lines.add(points);
    repaint();      
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponents(g);

    for(ArrayList<Point> p : lines)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < points.size()-1; i++)
            g.drawLine(points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y, points.get(i+1).x, points.get(i+1).y);
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)  {}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)   {}
@Override 
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)  
{
    points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    points.add(e.getPoint());
    repaint();
}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)    {}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
{
    if(evt.getSource()== clearButton)
    {
        lines.clear();
        points.clear();
        repaint();
    }

}




}
```

Main method:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainDriver 
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Draw d = new Draw();
    frame.add(d);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: Please specify your problem, not just a dump of code for us to read.

Comment: And create an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Problem is specified in the title. I hit run, make a few lines here and there. When I resize or minimize the window, everything except the last line that was drawn is erased from the jframe.

Comment: **NEVER-EVER** store  a `Graphics` object that you fetched with `component.getGraphics();`. Don't override `paint`, but `paintComponent`. Don't call `super.paintComponents(g);` but `super.paintComponent(g);`. Read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ (and thousands of examples of custom painting that you can find everywhere)

Comment: @Marco13 thanks for the advice. I've made those changes. However now another problem has arisen. Normally, I could make as many lines as I wanted. Now that I'm using     super.paintComponent(g) - the last drawn item disappears the moment I start drawing a new one :(

Comment: In your `paint` method (that is *now* called `paintComponent`, replace every `points` with `p`.

Comment: @Marco13 You are a genius. I'm seeing now why it was doing what it was. And I feel like an idiot for not seeing it before. If you want to answer the question, I can mark yours as the answer. Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - it's certainly only looking for debugging help, and is not likely to be helpful for future visitors (lots of examples for such "drawing programs" can be found on the web). Let's leave it like that....